# Make the timestamp on the Question page always a link to the revised post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timestamps, questions-page

When a post other than a question is revised (edited or a new answer posted), the "revised" timestamp on the Questions page is a link that takes you right to the post which was edited; useful and logical.

For some reason, when the revised post was the question (like when the question is first posted or an edit has been made but there are no answers yet) the revised link isn't a link anymore. It looks exactly the same but no longer functions.

Here's what the links look like:

[image]

The top timestamp isn't a link, because there are no answers. The bottom one *is* a link because the post has answers.

Can the revision timestamp just be made so it's always a link to the revised post, even if the question doesn't have answers?

Comment: Oddly enough Community's auto-bump makes the timestamp a link as well, even though there's no revision. Not sure if maybe this is a bug instead?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't formally complained about this before? It drives me *crazy*. I was under the impression it was strictly related to whether or not there were answers on the question, but I can't find a Community-bumped post that has 0 answers for some reason. It's also worth noting that the "active" sort of the questions list always links.

Comment: @TimStone Active page doesn't always link...the example is from the Active page. No link to this question right now.

Comment: Your example is from the front page, not the [active sort of the questions list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) (so the current behaviour is inconsistent as well as annoying).

Comment: Ah, right. Multiple pages named the same :P

Comment: + 1 for a right point

Comment: Posting a bounty on a question will also 'bump' it with a disabled timestamp...

Comment: @Lix if it doesn't have answers or just always?

Comment: @ben - seems indeed that it is related to the existence of answers...

Comment: @Lix seems to, editing a question with answers DOES give a link.

Answer (score 4):

This is already the case. The timestamp is only then not a link if there are no answers at all. If you e.g. look at this very question on the homepage, you'll see that the timestamp is indeed a link, and it ends up on the question itself.

But, for the sake of consistency, the timestamp will now be a direct link to the question in the zero answers case.

Comment: But that's not *always* a link; the part where it's not a link when there's no questions is what I wanted to change. There's still a question to link to, why not keep the same functionality?

Comment: Okay, your question says something else. Yeah, I can see that it would add some consistency, despite not actually being helpful. I'll check if I'm missing a possible issue here, otherwise I'll remove the ">0 answers" requirement.

Comment: Oops, yeah I figured out why it was doing that after writing the post, at first I thought it was just edits to the question that never caused a link.

Comment: Well, it'd be helpful in the sense that I don't have to shake my fist at the monitor when I go to click the non-link since I don't know what changed. That whole "Look at the answer count first and decide what to click" is too much effort for my liking. :P

Comment: @TimStone finally!

Comment: @BenBrocka Huh? That change has been in for weeks. Tim just updated the text to reflect what I said in the comments.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yeah, I saw Community bump the post and realised this hadn't gotten the up vote loving it deserved, despite the change having been in place for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I hope they assume that when you ask question you are more cleared about it rather than while you are giving answer(You can misunderstood problem sometimes and give answer).

So any changes to answer (Either revise or edit) it will lead you to answer to see the changes so that you get exact solution to your problem and avoid the case misleading(if edited).

But while you are asking question and somebody edit it then we generally change formatting and  spelling. The i had seen many edit of questions ,most of them are for spelling mistake, Remove greetings, and formatting.
So i give answer on my own assumption